# Laravel application fails to start after Composer update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

After updating composer using `composer update`, my application now fails to start.

Result of `php artisan -V`:

```
Laravel Framework version 4.1.19
```

**Error message:**

```
ErrorException

Route [admin.profile.index] not defined. (View: /var/www/laravel/app/views/back_end/menu.blade.php) (View: /var/www/laravel/app/views/back_end/menu.blade.php) (View: /var/www/laravel/app/views/back_end/menu.blade.php)


ErrorException

Route [admin.profile.update] not defined. (View: /var/www/laravel/app/views/back_end/layouts/profile.blade.php)
```

My Route:

```
Route::get('login', array('as'=>'login', function()
{
    return View::make('back_end.login');
}));
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
  Route::resource('admin/profile' , 'ProfileController' , array('as'=>'profile' , 'before'=>'csrf'));
});
```

`composer.json` content:

```
{
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
        "license": "MIT",
        "require": {
                "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
                "way/generators": "dev-master"
        },
        "autoload": {
                "classmap": [
                        "app/commands",
                        "app/controllers",
                        "app/models",
                        "app/database/migrations",
                        "app/database/seeds",
                        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
                ]
        },
        "scripts": {
                "post-install-cmd": [
                        "php artisan clear-compiled",
                        "php artisan optimize"
                ],
                "post-update-cmd": [
                        "php artisan clear-compiled",
                        "php artisan optimize"
                ],
                "post-create-project-cmd": [
                        "php artisan key:generate"
                ]
        },
        "config": {
                "preferred-install": "dist"
        },
        "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

ProfileController:

```
class ProfileController extends \BaseController {

    public $layout = 'back_end.layouts.main';
    public function index()
    {
        $profiles = Auth::user();
        return  View::make('back_end.layouts.profile')->with('profile', $profiles);
    }
}
```

Before the update, my application worked correctly and I had no problems.

Comment: try to `composer dump-autoload` on the laravel projects root folder. and recheck your views.

Comment: @majimboo. not any change. i have error. my application do not have any problem before update that.

Comment: where is this view called? `[admin.profile.index]`

Comment: @majimboo. from menu. `<a href="{{ URL::route('admin.profile.index') }}">profile Managment</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Of course - with **composer update**, you were updating packages and broke some of your code due to changes with updates. Composer update is reading from the composer.json file. You should run **composer install**, which is reading **composer.lock** file. **Composer.lock** is "locking" your dependencies to a known state, so you application can't crash.

Comment: in Way documents. he say for install way/generators must be update composer. how to install `way/generators` ?

Comment: Way generators install process:

first pull that package with composer require way/generators
next add a new service provider under app/config/app - service providers array
finally add new alias (optional) in the same file if you don't want to type long package name.
than update. as I sad update on a global level will update all packages - so be aware of that.